# eCommerce Monthly Membership with Digital Credit System

Tags: ecommerce

I'm hoping to find an affordable out-of-the-box eCommerce solution that can be configured to operate using digital credits in lieu of the traditional cart/checkout system.

I'd like to be able to enable membership tiers that allocate members a specific number of credits/downloads each month. In addition, it would be nice if users are able to also purchase credits separate from the recurring membership should they exhaust their supply before their monthly renewal.

Either something that will allow me to assign a credit cost to each item or even something where each product has an assigned value of 1 credit that is then subtracted from the users available credits.

Something similar to Adobe Substance 3D Assets or iStock.

I've looked at Squarespace and all I see are "Memberships" that grant access to gated content. Nothing about a digital credit purchasing system. I've also looked at Shopify and it appears theoretically possible, but only by using several plug-ins from multiple 3rd-party vendors with questionable ratings.